# I'm passing FUN = rank to ave, how do I makes ties.methods = "first"

Tags: r, rank

Perhaps this isn't possible, but I would like to specify a tie method while using rank as an argument in `ave`.

ie.

```
df <- ave(df$subset, df$subset2, FUN = rank, ties.method = "first)
```

`ave` doesn't appear to accept additional arguments for rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the anonymous function call here in `ave` as `ave` doesn't accept function arguments that should work elsewhere

```
with(df, ave(subset, subset2, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first)))
```

NOTE: Noticed that the output of `ave` is assigned to 'df'.  The output will be a `vector` and if we need a new column in the dataset, it is `df$newCol <-`

---

However, this anonymous call is not required for package solutions like `data.table` or `dplyr`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newCol := frank(subset, ties.method = "first"), by = subset2]
```

Comment: Thank's @akrun, this worked and is helpful to know in general, I think.